# what database architecture is a good choiche for this application?

Tags: java, mysql, database, sqlite, servlets

I have a servlet-based application that runs in a tomcat7 environment.
This application needs to manage users' files in such a way these files can be accessed in many ways and through different classification methods (for instance time-oriented classification and search, keywords, tags, author and so on).

So I have a multidimensional search space and I need to organize a database-based grouping system.

Let focus on a single and specific aspect.
Any user can upload his own files. So I'll have a path in which these files will be saved.

Then I need also a place where to store the informations associated to the files.
I though that it is good to separate files from associated informaions (title, ...) and then to create a third entity that is a small string that univocally identificate both info and file.
This way once i know the file id I can get both the informations (that are stored in a specific file) and the file but I can save this id in any perverse classification table without copying anything heavy.
So If I have the file id (fid) I can get the file and the informations. and when I have for example to associate an object to a file I can simply associate that object to the fid.

Then any user must have its own table that collects the variuos fid of the files he uploaded . 
Therefore I have one table for each user. Then for any other classification dimension I will have N tables (where N is the size of the dimension).  So for instance I want to classify files for keywords, I'll need N tables each for a specific keyboard. (it will be too unefficient to search each time I want files associated to key AGAA through all the users files)
So if I need to show the 50 more recent files associated to the keyword "AGAAA" I need a table for AGAAA. and so on.

This is crazy. as the number of users increases I get exponentialy more tables.
I heard about table limit per database in mysql databases. 
Until now I'm using mysql (mariaDB) with connection pooling.
I though to split tables of different "nature" (i.e. those of the keyboards, those fo the time and so on) in different databases (also in order to organize in a clearly way the contents). But with connection pooling I need to declare the database name in the resource definition. So for different databases I will need different pools.

Now questions.

- Using pooling I must create a different pool resource for each different database access. aint I?
- If yes, is It a good pratice to use the same database for all the different kind of tables?
- If no. How can change database runtime?
- I thought I could manage different tables with different database systems. for example I could use SQLite in order to manage classification tables, mysql to manage user interaction and so on. Is this a good pratice?
- Is SQLite in general faster than server-based databases in multi-user applications?
- Can I use connection pooling with SQLite ? I mean, what are SQLite connection if SQLite has no server? and does it make sense to think about connection pooling?
- What database architecture do you suggest for this kind of problematics?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why would each user or keyword need its own table? Tables can have many rows.

> Using pooling I must create a different pool resource for each
>   different database access. aint I?

Your question has multiple meanings, but generally you create one pool for one application, and it manages itself.

> If yes, is It a good pratice to use the same database for all the
>   different kind of tables? If no. How can change database runtime?

Generally one would use one database for an application.

> I thought I could manage different tables with different database
>   systems. for example I could use SQLite in order to manage
>   classification tables, mysql to manage user interaction and so on. Is
>   this a good pratice?

You could, but that would be insane.

> Is SQLite in general faster than server-based databases in multi-user
>   applications?

Absolutely not. SQLite can only have one writer at a time, though it is fine for many readers.

> Can I use connection pooling with SQLite ? I mean, what are SQLite
>   connection if SQLite has no server? and does it make sense to think
>   about connection pooling?

I don't know, but you shouldn't use SQLite if you expect multiple concurrent users writing / uploading to the database.

> What database architecture do you suggest for this kind of
>   problematics?

I would suggest you use a content repository like Apache JackRabbit, or a search server like Apache Solr.

Comment: Thank you very much for replying. 
each "classification key" must have its own table because otherwise I'll need multidimensional tables. Indeed if I need to group files for author I can create a single table each row associated to any user and then I need to use columns to store info about files.

Comment: But I need to specify column size at creation time so I have a upper limit to indexable files per user. Then a signle table will quickly increase as the number of user and files. I dont think it is a winning approach. And what if I want to add a keword classification? I add a dimension. Should I search the entire file table aech time a look for files associated to a key? I dont think so. I think is more efficient to have more tables. is this a bad approach in your opinion?

anyway I will check all your suggests, thanks!